# Drupal Facebook login fetchs userid as email insead of original email address

Tags: facebook, drupal, drupal-7, facebook-login, fbconnect

I am using [Fboauth](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwiz1Yb2q9XHAhXPBY4KHaXcDbs&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.drupal.org%2Fproject%2Ffboauth&ei=yVflVfPMC8-LuASlubfYCw&usg=AFQjCNHasibETzn_J55CXd4BGPX-uinsIQ&sig2=SQ0fgZNv9xpk7I2wQoNs8w) for facebook login. I have created new appid in **developer.facebook.com**. Facebook login works fine, problem is it fetches some numeric id as email address instead of original email address.The email address I am getting is

> Email: 102356987452358@facebook.com

In the email address field I am getting this. Please tell me how to resolve it. Thank You

Comment: You should ask the Fboauth maintainers about this. Most likely they have not adapted their code yet in regard to the changes API v2.4 brought concerning the fields returned. (And then they are most likely just using user-id@facebook.com as a fallback, if the email could not be read.)

Comment: You could try [hybridauth](https://www.drupal.org/project/hybridauth) module instead. As far as I know, hybridauth library has no problems with Facebook login integration.